# Master-Detail relation with inheritance in a WPF MVVM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I think this is a rather basic question, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this.

I have the following scenario:
Without using any form of EntityFrameWork I have a PersonViewModel and a PersonDetailsViewModel, which inherits from the PersonViewModel. In my PersonView I display a collection of PersonViewModels in a grid. I have properties like Name, DateOfBirth etc, as columns. When I double click on a person a PersonDetailView pops up which is bound to a PersonDetailsViewModel. In this View there is extra information shown about the person (Gender, SocialSecurity number etc.). The user I allowed to edit all properties.

Now I wonder what the best/common approach is to make sure that the PersonViewModel gets updated with the values that have been editted in the PersonDetailsViewModel.

I can think of several options. For starters I could opt for not using different ViewModels, but instead use PersonDetailViewModels to show in the grid, but the downside to that is that I would need to retrieve a lot of unnecessary data per ViewModel.
I can also synchronise the corresponding properties after the PersonDetailsView closes.
The third option I can think of is that instead of inheriting from the PersonView I will include a property in PersonDetailsView that is of the type PersonView and expose it's properties and use it for binding in the PersonDetailsView. All other extra properties in PersonDetailsViewModel will then be retrieved in it's constructor.

Comment: if you do MVVM with Viewmodel First and implement INotitfyPropertyChanged and every PersonViewmodel has its own PersonDetailsViewmodel then you dont have do to anything.

Comment: btw posting some code would help all to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Addition to Sheridans answer. i would expose the Detail as a property of type PersonDetailsViewModel

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonDetailsViewModel Detail {get;set;}
}
```

then your xaml looks simply like that

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Detail.Gender}"/>
```

EDIT1: in addition to the comments above

i would not do any inheritence (thats what user1087702 wrote in his question). i would simply create 2 classes: PersonVM and PersonVMDetail. And if the request is, to show Details from my person object, why in hell shouldn't i just create a public Property in my PersonVM class of type PersonVMDetail - to fullfill this request?

Comment: For now this approach is the easiest for me to implement. It's actually so straightforward, that I feel silly not having thought of it myself.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best way to update view models who share the same data is to use the [Mediator](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html) pattern to send a notification message that the data has updated.

> In order to have a good object oriented design we have to create lots
>   of classes interacting one with each other. If certain principles are
>   not applied the final framework will end in a total mess where each
>   object relies on many other objects in order to run. In order to avoid
>   tight coupled frameworks, we need a mechanism to facilitate the
>   interaction between objects in a manner in that objects are not aware
>   of the existence of other objects.
>
> *Source [http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html_)*

It is syntactically important to your design that the notification says what *has happened* (the data was updated) and not what *should happen* (data gets reloaded) because that response may not stay the same as the system evolves.

Often, common MVVM libraries have Mediator implementations in them. For example, Prism's `EventAggregator`.

Comment: I agree with Gusdor, another simple explanation would be: use event driven architecture to inform the rest of the system when a particular object was updated.

Comment: why using a mediator pattern when you just wanna show some details for a person class? the person class itself should have of course an instance of its detail object

Comment: @blindmeis i would counter that disconnecting notification from your inheritence structure lets you concentrate on the functional detail rather than agonising about if the implementation will stuff you in the long run. Master and Detail have different functions and it feels like good SRP to disconnect them in all but name. By all means, use a flyweight for the shared data.

Comment: I will have to look into the mediator pattern, as I am currently not familiar how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve your requirements would be to add a constructor to your `PersonViewModel` class that takes a `PersonDetailsViewModel` instance and updates its common properties:

```
public PersonViewModel(PersonDetailsViewModel personDetailsViewModel)
{
    Name = personDetailsViewModel.Name;
    ...
    DateOfBirth = personDetailsViewModel.DateOfBirth;
}
```

...

```
PersonViewModel = new PersonViewModel(PersonDetailsViewModel);
```

Of course, this doesn't have to be in the constructor... it could just as easily be a method in the `PersonViewModel` class, or even a helper method in a separate Factory Pattern class, it's up to you.

Comment: Should it not be the other way around? I mean the PersonDetailViewModel having a constructor that takes the PersonViewModel.

Comment: Hey, they're *your* requirements... you said *I wonder what the best/common approach is to make sure that the `PersonViewModel` gets updated with the values that have been edited in the `PersonDetailsViewModel`*. At the end of the day, you just need to copy the property values across... it doesn't really matter how or where you do that... it's up to you.